# Images not display on Chrome and FF

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I store images in mysql database and with the help of image path and name I retrieve images on datalist by using image hyperlink. Now I am facing a problem that the images are displaying on IE but not on FF and chrome. My side aspx code is below:

```
 <div>
    <asp:DataList ID="dtlistImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
            <ItemTemplate>
        
            <asp:hyperlink ID="Hyperlink1" style="float:right; margin:5px; margin-left:10px; border:2px solid #BAB9BE;" Width="90px" Height="95px" runat="server" NavigateURL='<%# Eval("img_big") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("img_tb") %>' Autopostback="true" />    </br>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pageNumber") %>' Font-Bold="true"
                            Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#336699" Width="100%"/>                            
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" />    
    </asp:DataList>
    </div>
```

Images shown snap shot on chrome is like(not displaying images):
[image]

Images shown snap shot on IE is like(displaying images):
[image]

What is the real problem I am facing. I use html image tag, asp Image, ImageButton but not display single pic thumbnail. Why???? When I see the view source the thumbnail image source is accurate but not display image on data list. This problem is i am facing on FF and Chrome only, IE show exactly what I want. Please help me out of this stuck. Images are store in Mysql and I am using .net IDE.

Comment: What is the rendered html? Also you have some issues with capitalization and events (specifically when `OnClick` can be used) in your code.

Comment: could you clean up the code sample - it is full of commented-out code that seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: @Kanagis: I not remove the commented tag to show that I use all possible image tag to display Images but not succeed

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: OnClick was used on image tag which i commented and used asp:hyperlink as i also want to navigate url when click on image thumbnail and on hyperlink control I not used OnClick, then why same problem I am facing. I reinstall FF and chrome but not solved problem yet :(

Comment: @Mohsinjan110 My point was, OnClick has different meanings in the ways you used it. `OnClick` != `onclick`

Comment: Now I edit code section which I am running now. Not any onclick or OnClick event is used! Still images are not displayed on FF and chrome

Answer (score 0):

You should not render the image links using file shares. Instead you have to:

- create a custom handler (page) that reads the image from the share and return it in HTTP response

  -or -
- map that share as virtual directory in IIS and point the links there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mike, the rendered HTML would be helpful.  On line 4 of your code snippet, you start an anchor tag.  The closing tag is commented out.  Maybe IE is just more forgiving with malformed HTML?  The Hyperlink control also doens't have an AutoPostBack property.